# Cordova FileTransfer Addon - Refreshes Back To App Root

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an Ionic App using the ngCordova FileTransfer plugin. I have it installed and setup. I have a click function in my view modeled to the function that should be downloading the file in my App. I am building my url and filename from data returned by a service.

When I tap the link, it pops open to a new "view" in the app which is the default state from my app.js file. I'm sure I'm missing something small. Can someone take a look at this and let me know if they see anything glaring?

```
$scope.showProgress = false;
$scope.downloadLink = function () {

var index;
var formLinks;
for (index = 0; index < $scope.formularyLookupDetails.length; index++) {
  formLinks = $scope.formularyLookupDetails[index];
}

var filename = formLinks.LinkUrl.split("/").pop();
var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
var options = {};
var trustHosts = true;

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(formLinks.LinkUrl, targetPath, options, trustHosts).then(function (result) {

}, function (err) {

}, function (progress) {
  $scope.showProgress = true;
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
  });
});
```

};

Comment: which version of android are using? Does your service returns a valid URL? Any error trace?

Comment: I'm using Marshmallow. The service does return valid url as when debugging in-browser just returning links to the view using ng-repeat, I'm able to download, but when I perform ionic build with Cordova FileTransfer it just opens new window to default route. I don't know if there is an error trace as I'm doing a build to .apk.

Comment: could be a possible permission issue related to file plugin with marshmallow. You may have to look at fileutils.java file in android src of file plugin to pull the fix for this permission issue

Comment: I was able to get it to download the file, which I'll call a small success. The other issue now is I get no progress bar for the download. It just shows up on the device and never notifies the user that anything has taken place. Is there some specific modeling that needs to take place in the view to show a progress bar of the download or to get the devices native progress indicator to show the download progress?

Comment: i m not sure about ionic framework.But i have managed the progress indicator in my app by using jquery mobile loader. I invoked loading indicator before calling file download and hide the indicator in file download success callback.